# Opposing class cast exceptions in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have an issue that is making me a little nuts. Here is the Java method.

```
public List<FtpActiveMerchantDTO> getFtpActiveMerchants() {

    String sql = "select m.merchantId, ma.merchantAcctId, m.domain, f.fetchUrl, ma.acctActive, " +
            "f.fieldDelimiter, f.feedType " +
            "from merchant_account ma " +
            "join merchant_ftp_account f on f.merchantAcctId = ma.merchantAcctId " +
            "join merchant m on m.merchantAcctId = ma.merchantAcctId " +
            "where f.fetchUrl is not null and ma.acctActive = 1";

    Query query = currentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);

    List<FtpActiveMerchantDTO> ftpActiveMerchantDTOList = new ArrayList<FtpActiveMerchantDTO>();
    int merchantId, merchantAcctId;
    byte acctActive;
    for (Object rowObject : query.list()) {
        Object[] row = (Object []) rowObject;
        merchantId = ((BigDecimal) row[0]).intValue();
        merchantAcctId = ((BigDecimal) row[1]).intValue();
        acctActive = ((BigDecimal) row[4]).byteValue();
        ftpActiveMerchantDTOList.add(new FtpActiveMerchantDTOBuilder().withMerchantId(merchantId)
                .withMerchantAcctId(merchantAcctId).withDomain((String) row[2])
                .withFetchUrl((String) row[3]).withAcctActive(acctActive > 0)
                .withFieldDelimiter(row[5].toString()).withFeedType((String) row[6]).build());
    }

    return ftpActiveMerchantDTOList;
}
```

When I run my service with the code as it is shown here, I get

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/merchants/ftpActive
{"responseData":null,"errorData":[{"code":500,"detailMessage":"","message":"java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal"}],"debugData":null}
```

The error is occurring at the line where `acctActive` is assigned. When I fix that line to this:

```
acctActive = (Byte) row[4];
```

then the *service* works as expected. But then my *integration test* (run from within IntelliJ)

```
private void whenFetchingFtpActiveMerchants() {
    openAndBindSession();
    ftpActiveMerchantDTOList = merchantDAO.getFtpActiveMerchants();
    flushAndCloseSession();
}
```

fails, with this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Byte
at com.pronto.mpds.dal.MerchantDAOImpl.getFtpActiveMerchants(MerchantDAOImpl.java:143)
at com.pronto.mpds.dal.MerchantDAOIT.whenFetchingFtpActiveMerchants(MerchantDAOIT.java:96)
at com.pronto.mpds.dal.MerchantDAOIT.testFtpActiveMerchants(MerchantDAOIT.java:44)
...
```

The field in the db table is a tinyint(4). Why would the results from the db query be "expecting" to be a BigDecimal? Is there some kind of default data type? I know I am not configuring one anywhere.

Comment: Are you using the same database in your integration test? If you are it looks like they have different schemas.

Comment: You need to use scalar to explicitly specify the type.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid, but are you 100% sure that your unit test is not somehow using the old code (e.g. old jar in the classpath)?

Comment: @Nambari - where in the code would you do this?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html

Comment: @Giodude i didn't realize it but this is correct - they are different! if you want to add it as an answer i can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance it looks like the database schema for the integration test is different from the production one, thus the type mismatch.

Comment: This uncovered some other inconsistencies between the two dbs, not surprisingly, so it took a little while to resolve, but this was the cause of the problem and fixing the db inconsistencies resolved the issue. Yay for integration tests :)